# C++ extern vector variable error

Tags: c++, vector, extern

In "BarOperations.h"

```
#include "Bar.h"
#include "Piv.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
...
extern std::vector<Bar> bars;
...
```

In "Bar.h"

```
class Bar {...};
...
```

In "main.cpp"

```
vector<Bar> bars;
...
```

But I received the following error:

> syntax error: missing ";" before identifier 'bars'

I am not familiar with usage of "extern", could anyone help provide some explanation?
I want to use variable 'bars' defined in main.cpp in "BarOperations.h" by using "extern".

Comment: Did you include `vector` ?

Comment: Check your compiler output; particularly the one before what you've mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I did include <vector>

Comment: In that case, please include the code for `Bar.h`, `Piv.h` and any relevant line above `bars`. I can't really see what else could be the cause, though...

Comment: I didn't have bars in    Bar.h /     Piv.h, instead I have     bars defined in main.cpp. Is it the problem?

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Your compiler needs to know about `Bar` before reaching that line, otherwise that will not work. Basically, if `Bar` is not in `Bar.h`, `Piv.h` or in the lines above your vector then yep, you found your problem !

Comment: 'Bar' is defined in Bar.h, but the variable 'bars' is defined in main.cpp. I will post related fragments.

Answer (score 4):

`extern` in a variable declaration means that this is a pure declaration (not a definition) of a variable with external linkage defined somewhere else in the program. If the variable is used, then there must also be exactly one definition somewhere in the program; that will be exactly the same but without the `extern`.

But that's irrelevant to the error: it looks like the compiler doesn't recognise `std::vector`, probably because you haven't included `<vector>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But it is due to I forgetfully didn't write

```
using namespace std;
```

After adding this after the `#include <...>` the issue is solved.